# user_save() with multiple select fields like checkboxes or selection fields

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

My custom registration form module hass a selection field that allows new users to select one or more cities.  In my search, I have not found any examples to draw from.  Does anyone have an example of what 'field_city' => should look like in the following code if the city keys to be saved are 20 and 53, for example?

```
$edit = array(
  'name' => 'tester',
  'pass' => user_password(),
  'mail' => 'tester@testing.com',
  'status' => 0,
  'init' => 'tester@testing.com',
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'field_city' => ,
  'field_zip_postal_code' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => '12345'))),
  'field_gender' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => 'Male'))),
);

user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out on my own. If it helps anyone, for taxonomy term references, the column name is 'tid' and not 'value' as it is for other fields. I changed the registration code to the following:

```
$edit = array(
  'name' => $form_state['step_information'][2]['stored_values']['name'],
  'pass' => user_password(),
  'mail' => $form_state['step_information'][2]['stored_values']['email'],
  'status' => 0,
  'init' => $form_state['step_information'][2]['stored_values']['email'],
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'field_zip_postal_code' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['step_information'][3]['stored_values']['postal_code']))),
  'field_gender' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['step_information'][3]['stored_values']['gender']))),
);

foreach(array_keys($form_state['step_information'][1]['stored_values']['cities']) as $key => $val) {
  $edit['field_city'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$key] = array('tid' => $val);
}

$new_account = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
```

In the 'foreach' loop, '$key' is a cardinal number (0, 1, 2...) that gets stored in the 'delta' column in the database and '$val' is the city's ID.